# when to use $destroy

Tags: angularjs, stream, destroy, oboe.js

I have a get request in angular that returns a streaming response. The request is made through the [oboe](http://oboejs.com/) library. The streaming response basically returns json values and my angular front end adds each of these streams to the scope on receiving each json object. Since oboe is not a part of angular itself, I am using $scope.$digest to update my scope. This is cause a huge memory leak for larger requests. I have figured that I have to use $destroy at some point. Can someone please tell me on which event I should use the $destroy for optimal performance?

Answer (score 0):

I would have to think a little more about the angular internals to give a good answer. However, have you considered using https://github.com/RonB/angular-oboe, or talking a look at how that project deals with updates? They don't seem to use either `$digest` or `$destoy`